# i successfully installed tensorflow in anaconda prompt, but unable import in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow

ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.
Reason: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pratap\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

- Python version is 3.8.
- The official distribution of TensorFlow for Windows requires Python version 3.5 or 3.6.
- TensorFlow is installed at: C:\Users\pratap\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow
- msvcp140.dll Found at C:\Users\pratap\Anaconda3\msvcp140.dll
- Could not load 'cudart64_90.dll'. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from
  this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
- Could not load 'nvcuda.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow requires that
  this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
  environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'.
  If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the
  correct driver installed.
- Could not load 'cudnn64_7.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow
  requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in
  your %PATH% environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a
  separate step from installing CUDA, and it is often found in a
  different directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the
  necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN 7.0 for Cuda 9.0 from this URL:
  https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn
  An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: -1

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow supports python3.8 starting from version 2.2.

I would recommend running `conda install python=3.6` and taking it from there.